# Can't take react-bootstrap component event target value

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap, fetch-api, mern

I currently using react-bootstrap (4.6) library to render code. So far, I've mapped out an array that gives out `eachProdcut` from my database. However, I tried accessing the value upon click but it sent me either `undefined` or the supposedly expected value `_id`.

I tried using `.persist()` from the Event Pooling (https://reactjs.org/docs/legacy-event-pooling.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper). Although, I somehow still sometimes receive that `undefined` value.

As for the `onClick` event, I tried passing down the usual arrow function to handle the event `event => select(event)` but to no success.

**(code)** id trying to access:

```
<ListGroup.Item action onClick={select} className="product-item" key={eachProduct._id} value={eachProduct._id}>
        <Row>
            <Col>
                {eachProduct.name}
            </Col>
            <Col className="text-right">
                {eachProduct.isActive ?
                    <strong className="text-success">Active</strong>:
                    <strong className="text-danger">Inactive</strong>}
            </Col>
        </Row>
</ListGroup.Item>
```

**(code)** function trying to take id:

```
const select = (event) => {
   event.persist()
   console.log(event.target.value) // returning either undefined or expected output id
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems to work after using `event.currentTarget.value` instead of `event.target.value`